# Плагин jQuery для Select по типу datalist?

Tags: jquery, select, datalist

Стандартные, такие как Chosen или Select2 не подходят, т.к. не позволяют ввести данные, которых нет в списке.

Мне нужен Input, который во время ввода текста делает подсказки по подготовленному списку. По клику на Input должен выпадать список.

Может как-то модицифировать Chosen или Select2 ? Чтобы если нет совпадения, текст не стирался.

Или как стилизировать стандартный выпадающий список datalist? Но использование datalist нежелательно, т.к. не всеми браузерами он поддерживается.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = ["lol", "kek", "cheburek"];
console.clear();

$("#inp").on("keyup", function() {
 var m = $("#m");
        m.html("");
 inp = $("#inp").val();
 data.forEach(function(child) {
      if(child.indexOf(inp)!==-1) {
               m.append(child + "<br>")
           }
        });
});

$("#inp").focus(function() {
  var m = $("#m");
  m.html("");
  data.forEach(function(child) {
    if(child.indexOf(inp)!==-1) {
     m.append(child + "<br>")
    }
  });
});

$("#inp").focusout(function() {
  var m = $("#m");
  m.html("");
});
```

```css
#m {
  background-color: #1C90F3;
  width: 25%;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inp" autocomplete="off">
<div id="m"></div>
```